# How can I map NHibernate domain classes with an existing table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am presently trying to use NHibernate on a project where I do not have permissions to CREATE TABLE in SQL 2005.

I keep getting a mapping error, and my assumption is that I do not setup the table by generating it. Is it fair of me to assume that NHibernate can only map successfully with tables that were generated by its tool?

If not, how can I make sure it works for an existing table?

---

14 Sept
Responding to request to provide more details:

```
<id name="MeetingID" column="MeetingID" type="int">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="Description" />
<property name="OwnerNetworkID"  />
<property name="StartDate" />
<property name="EndDate" />
<property name="DayStartHour" />
<property name="DayStartMinute" />
<property name="DayEndHour" />
<property name="DayEndMinute" />
<property name="BreakStartHour" />
<property name="BreakStartMinute" />
<property name="BreakEndHour" />
<property name="BreakEndMinute" />
<property name="IsActive" />
<property name="SessionIntervalMinutes" />
<property name="PeoplePerSlot" />
<property name="DateCreated" />
<property name="LastModified" />
<property name="UpdatedBy" />
<property name="ChangeTimestamp" />
<property name="ClosedForBookingDaysPrior" />
<property name="DefaultMeetingRoom" />
```

This is the class:

Namespace MyNamespace
    Public Class Meeting

```
    Private _MeetingID As Integer
    Private _OwnerNetworkID As String
    Private _Description As String

    Public Overridable Property MeetingID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _MeetingID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _MeetingID = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Overridable Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return _Description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property OwnerNetworkID() As String
        Get
            Return _OwnerNetworkID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _OwnerNetworkID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _StartDate As Date
    Public Overridable Property StartDate() As Date
        Get
            Return _StartDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _StartDate = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _EndDate As Date
    Public Overridable Property EndDate() As Date
        Get
            Return _EndDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _EndDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DayStartHour As Byte
    Public Overridable Property DayStartHour() As Byte
        Get
            Return _DayStartHour
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _DayStartHour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DayStartMinute As Byte
    Public Overridable Property DayStartMinute() As Byte
        Get
            Return _DayStartMinute
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _DayStartMinute = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DayEndHour As Byte
    Public Overridable Property DayEndHour() As Byte
        Get
            Return _DayEndHour
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _DayEndHour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DayEndMinute As Byte
    Public Overridable Property DayEndMinute() As Byte
        Get
            Return _DayEndMinute
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _DayEndMinute = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _BreakStartHour As Byte
    Public Overridable Property BreakStartHour() As Byte
        Get
            Return _BreakStartHour
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _BreakStartHour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _BreakStartMinute As Byte
    Public Overridable Property BreakStartMinute() As Byte
        Get
            Return _BreakStartMinute
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _BreakStartMinute = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _BreakEndHour As Byte
    Public Overridable Property BreakEndHour() As Byte
        Get
            Return _BreakEndHour
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _BreakEndHour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _BreakEndMinute As Byte
    Public Overridable Property BreakEndMinute() As Byte
        Get
            Return _BreakEndMinute
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _BreakEndMinute = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _IsActive As Byte
    Public Overridable Property IsActive() As Byte
        Get
            Return _IsActive
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _IsActive = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _SessionIntervalMinutes As Byte
    Public Overridable Property SessionIntervalMinutes() As Byte
        Get
            Return _SessionIntervalMinutes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _SessionIntervalMinutes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _PeoplePerSlot As Short
    Public Overridable Property PeoplePerSlot() As Short
        Get
            Return _PeoplePerSlot
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Short)
            _PeoplePerSlot = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DateCreated As Date
    Public Overridable Property DateCreated() As Date
        Get
            Return _DateCreated
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _DateCreated = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _LastModified As Date
    Public Overridable Property LastModified() As Date
        Get
            Return _LastModified
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _LastModified = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _UpdatedBy As String
    Public Overridable Property UpdatedBy() As String
        Get
            Return _UpdatedBy
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UpdatedBy = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ChangeTimestamp As Byte()
    Public Overridable Property ChangeTimestamp() As Byte()
        Get
            Return _ChangeTimestamp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte())
            _ChangeTimestamp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ClosedForBookingDaysPrior As Byte
    Public Overridable Property ClosedForBookingDaysPrior() As Byte
        Get
            Return _ClosedForBookingDaysPrior
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _ClosedForBookingDaysPrior = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DefaultMeetingRoom As String
    Public Overridable Property DefaultMeetingRoom() As String
        Get
            Return _DefaultMeetingRoom
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _DefaultMeetingRoom = value
        End Set
    End Property




End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Your assumption is wrong :) Nhibernate works with existing tables, it creates no table. Could you paste your mapping?

Comment: @Claudio NHibernate can create tables if you do an SchemaExport.Create(true, true);

Comment: @user Can you show us a <code>example</code>? Of course it's possible to use existing tables, we just need to see where you made the mistake. :)

Comment: @Rafael Belliard: Thanks for the clarification. That's a corner case. The user is stuck on a simpler scenario :)

Comment: Hi Huys, I have supplied the mapping above and the vb class. Perhaps you can tell me what I am doing wrong with my mapping. It would help if you could also refer me to examples where I may use NHibernate on an existing table without regenerating.

Comment: Please Tachi, paste the error description.

Comment: @Claudio - Sorry I took so long with it. I have resolved this but here is the error I got

Test 'Scheduler.Test.MeetingFixture.CanAddNewMeeting' failed: NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: Scheduler.Data.Meeting.hbm.xml
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find the dialect in the configuration
 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of my problem.

The error was cause by me not calling the Configure() method before calling  AddAssembly(typeof(Type)). This happens when I create a SessionFactory object.

Here is the VB example of this solution:

**Before**

```
    Private Shared ReadOnly Property SessionFactory() As ISessionFactory
        Get
            If _sessionFactory Is Nothing Then
                Dim configuration As New Configuration
                  configuration.AddAssembly(GetType(Meeting).Assembly)
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory

            End If
            Return _sessionFactory
        End Get
    End Property
```

**After**

```
    Private Shared ReadOnly Property SessionFactory() As ISessionFactory
        Get
            If _sessionFactory Is Nothing Then
                Dim configuration As New Configuration

                //Was missing
                configuration.Configure()
                //Configure 
                configuration.AddAssembly(GetType(Meeting).Assembly)
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory

            End If
            Return _sessionFactory
        End Get
    End Property
```